# evil-insert-state disables the active input method

Tags: evil, mu4e, input-method

A recent update must have slipped my testing afterwords and now this hook `mu4e-compose-mode-hook` does not work anymore.
On every new email I must set the input-method manually again.

Any ideas about how to fix this behaviour?

```lisp
(add-hook 'mu4e-compose-mode-hook
          (lambda () (set-input-method "german-postfix")))
```

tried this snippet as well without success

```lisp
  (add-hook 'mu4e-compose-mode-hook 'my-mu4e-mode-hook)
  (defun my-mu4e-mode-hook ()
    "Custom behaviours for `mu4e-compose-mode'."
    (activate-input-method "german-postfix"))
```

### Notes

`C-h v major-mode`

```
  major-mode is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.

  Its value is ‘mu4e-compose-mode’
  Original value was ‘fundamental-mode’
  Local in buffer *draft*; global value is fundamental-mode
```

`C-h v mu4e-compose-mode-hook`

```
  mu4e-compose-mode-hook is a variable defined in ‘mu4e-compose.el’.

  Its value is
  ((lambda nil
    (use-hard-newlines t 'guess))
  my-mu4e-mode-hook)
```

`M-x trace-function RET activate-input-method RET`

```
  ======================================================================
  1 -> (activate-input-method "german-postfix")
  1 <- activate-input-method: nil
```

**The moment I start composing the message / typing:**

```
  ======================================================================
  1 -> (activate-input-method nil)
  1 <- activate-input-method: nil
  ======================================================================
```

`M-x debug-on-entry RET activate-input-method RET`

**Initially:**

```
Debugger entered--entering a function:
* activate-input-method("german-postfix")
  my-mu4e-mode-hook()
  run-hooks(change-major-mode-after-body-hook text-mode-hook message-mode-hook mu4e-compose-mode-hook)
  apply(run-hooks (change-major-mode-after-body-hook text-mode-hook message-mode-hook mu4e-compose-mode-hook))
  run-mode-hooks(mu4e-compose-mode-hook)
  mu4e-compose-mode()
  mu4e~compose-handler(new)
  mu4e-compose(new)
  mu4e-compose-new()
  funcall-interactively(mu4e-compose-new)
  call-interactively(mu4e-compose-new nil nil)
  command-execute(mu4e-compose-new)
```

**Upon hitting `i` to insert text / compose message:**

```
* activate-input-method(nil)
  evil-insert-state(1)
  evil-insert(1 nil nil)
  evil-append(1 nil)
  funcall-interactively(evil-append 1 nil)
  call-interactively(evil-append nil nil)
  command-execute(evil-append)
```

Comment: Does `C-h v mu4e-compose-mode-hook` show anything unexpected?

Comment: If the hook value looks good, I suggest running `M-x trace-function RET activate-input-method RET` and then composing a new message (`untrace-function` to remove).  If there's an unexpected call, then use `M-x debug-on-entry RET activate-input-method RET` and find out where it's coming from (`cancel-debug-on-entry` to remove).  See `C-h i g (elisp)Debugger Commands` for driving the debugger.  Edit any relevant details into your question.

Comment: I strongly recommend *NOT* using the lambda approach in any case -- lambdas in hooks are a bad idea in general... they make the hook hard to inspect; the functions themselves can't be updated and are annoying to remove; and they can't be linked to the source code.  Using named functions avoids all these issues.

Comment: Good updates.  Your hook is clearly working, but something else deactivates the input method again afterwards, so it's that *second* call `(activate-input-method nil)` you want the debugger to tell you about.  Check the debugger command documentation again, and use `c` to continue execution until you trigger the second call, and then show the backtrace for that.

Comment: Perfect, we can see clearly that it's `evil-insert-state` which is disabling the active input method.  Why?  I have no idea -- I don't use `evil`, so I'll leave it to someone who has that installed to provide an Answer for you -- but I think that's a very clear question now.

Comment: One more question from me: You said this used to work, and now it doesn't.  Is it possible that when this was working you weren't yet using evil?

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have always been using evil

Comment: n.b. A workaround may be to update your hook so that it enables `evil-insert-state` first and *then* sets the input method.  (Whether that gets remembered if you also then switch back to the other evil state I couldn't say, but you could try it both ways.)

Comment: @since your last comment about the workaround solves my problem you might consider putting it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, a successful workaround is to update your hook function so that it enables `evil-insert-state` first and *then* sets the input method:

```el
(add-hook 'mu4e-compose-mode-hook 'my-mu4e-mode-hook)

(defun my-mu4e-mode-hook ()
  "Custom behaviours for `mu4e-compose-mode'."
  (evil-insert-state)
  (activate-input-method "german-postfix"))
```

Comment: @jjk Please make edits to this answer to add details/clarity as appropriate.  I've used a *slightly* different approach to the code you added to your answer, which I would expect to be equivalent; but obviously I've not tested it.